# What happens to the voltage through the transistor?

Tags: transistors, homework

[image]

In Figure above, I was asked: "If the wiper moves more towards point B, what will happen to:

> the base current, V1 (the voltage through the collector resistance) and V2.

The answer was that:

> the base current decreases.
>
> V1 decreases.
>
> V2 increases.

I would understand the variation happening to both V1 and V2 since the base current decreases, but I don't get why does the base current decreases anyway. Could anyone explain it for me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Base current doesn't change. It's always 0 because there's no return path for any current that does flow in to the base.

Comment: Did you mean to draw a common ground between the two voltage sources?

Comment: @ThePhoton, I actually don't know, I am confused. That's how it is drawn in my text book, and I don't actually know if the drawing depicts a common base transistor or what. And it says that there will be a change in the base current. And I didn't understand that there will be no path for any current! Because, you know, it's a transistor, the current entering the base will go out through the collector, right?

Comment: Get a proper text book is my advice. A floating voltage source has no effect on this circuit as photon says.

Comment: @Andyaka, I think that the book wasn't accurate enough and may be it meant that the resistance AB is a rheostat, so when the wiper moves the value of the resistance changes (increasing or decreasing I don't know for sure), and then the current (which enters the base) changes. So, what do you think?

Comment: There can not be any current into the base, or through Rb, because the potentiometer and bottom battery have no connection to the rest of the circuit.

Comment: What textbook are you using?

Comment: Yes, the resistor is a rheostat. Yes, the wiper makes contact at some point along the resistor. But still, KCL says current can't flow out of the lower subcircuit unless it has some way to flow back in.

Comment: Can you share a photo of the actual diagram in your textbook? Are you sure there are no ground symbols used in the diagram?

Comment: The drawing in the book is exactly as drawn in the figure above. it's my high school book. But you guys persuaded me. may be the book made a mistake.